# How can I set and use an environment variable in windows cmd in the same line?

Tags: windows, macos, cmd

A bit of background, on mac you can do something like this

```
PORT=3002 NODE_ENV=dev node server.js
```

But can you do the same on windows? I have tried

```
set PORT=3002 && echo %PORT%
```

but the variable does not update until the echo is called again.

The reason I need this is that i am currently using npm start to run a script on a mac that looks like the first line of code. This does not work in windows since you cannot set env variables like that.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what the mac command does.

Comment: It sets variables to use with the node server.js part of the command but only for this process, it does not affect system wide variables.

Comment: possible with [delayed Expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). What keeps you from using two lines?

Answer (score 4):

In most contexts, surround the variable name with `%'`s and the variable's value will be used 
e.g. To display the value of the `_department` variable with the ECHO command:

```
ECHO %_department%
```

Comment: Right but I need two commands inline, one to set the variable, one to run a server with that new variable. Windows doesnt seem to update that variable until a new command is called. Ie i cant set and echo a variable in the same line]

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set something=whatever&echo something=!something!
```

But you seem to have no reason for wanting this on a single line.

Comment: Seeming to have no reason and having no reason are different things. Edited question anyway.